# Dynamic Creation of textbox , dropdown list and other controls in java

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am working on an web application using strust2 framework, jsp ,java and cayenne as orm. I am new to all these technologies including ajax and jquery. I have to create a jsp page wherein user selects one of the controls(textbox, label,combo-box,dropdown) from a dropdown. which ever it selects and submits should be createed on the same page above.
It would be great if i could manage their sizes as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your service class you can add all the components, in an array, you want display in dropdown list. Just like this

```
ArrayList<String> htmlControls = new ArrayList<>();
htmlControls.add("input");
htmlControls.add("textarea");
htmlControls.add("checkbox");
```

then add this array list in HTTP *session* object like

```
session.setAttribute("htmlCtrls",htmlControls);
```

In your JSP, you can then use `JSTL for-each loop` to create dynamic dropdown list.

```
<c:forEach var="controls" items="${session.htmlCtrls}">
    <options><c:out value="${controls}"/></options> 
</c:forEach>
```

Apply `onChange()` event on `HTML select element` using JQuery

```
<script>
    $( "select" ).change(function () {
        var str = "";
        $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
            str = $( this ).text();
        });
        if(str == "input")
            $( "div" ).append("<input type='text' name='textbox1' value='' />");
        else if(str == "textarea")
            $( "div" ).append("<input type='textarea' name='textarea1' value='' />");
        // ...
    })
    .change();
</script>
```

You can add *class* or *id* to each html control & apply css dynamically to them using JQuery or by external css.

Hope this will help you.